# Getting this error: thread 1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I have developed an iOS application in swift 2.0 and have used a class called Reachability to determine whether the user is connected to the internet or not. The application runs, however the compiler stops and outputs this error:

> thread 1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0x0)

here is the code, and error occurs where the comment is.

```
func updateInterfaceWithReachability (reachability: Reachability)  {

    if reachability == self.hostReachability
    {
        self.checkStatus(reachability)

        let netStatus: NetworkStatus = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus()
        let connectionRequired: Bool = reachability.connectionRequired()

        var baseLabelText: NSString = ""

        if connectionRequired
        {
            baseLabelText = NSLocalizedString("Cellular data network is available.\nInternet traffic will be routed through it after a connection is established.", comment: "Reachability text if a connection is required")
        }
        else
        {
            baseLabelText = NSLocalizedString("Cellular data network is active.\nInternet traffic will be routed through it.", comment: "Reachability text if a connection is not required")
        }
    }


    if reachability == self.internetReachability  // error displayed here
    {
        self.checkStatus(reachability)
    }

    if reachability == self.wifiReachability
    {
        self.checkStatus(reachability)
    }

}
```

Also I declared internetReachability like this

```
var internetReachability: Reachability!
```

Also this is how i Initialized internetReachability in another function called checkStatus()

```
func checkInternetConnection () {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("reachabilityChanged"), name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)

    let remoteHostName: String = "www.apple.com"


    self.hostReachability = Reachability.init(hostName: remoteHostName)
    self.hostReachability.startNotifier()
    self.updateInterfaceWithReachability(self.hostReachability)

    self.internetReachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    self.internetReachability.startNotifier()
    self.updateInterfaceWithReachability(self.internetReachability)

    self.wifiReachability = Reachability.reachabilityForLocalWiFi()
    self.wifiReachability.startNotifier()
    self.updateInterfaceWithReachability(self.wifiReachability)
}
```

Do not understand what the error is and how to fix it. Help appreciated.

Comment: This is a big improvement of your previous question. I like that. The one thing you are still missing is the actual error message: the *found nil while unwrapping optional*-stuff! But still, this is a lot better than just a screenshot of the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code crashes on the given line because you declared the variable as implicitly unwrapped optional meaning that the value gets unwrapped in this situation to be able to compare it to `reachability`. But because you have not set anything to `internetReachability` yet, it is still `nil` and the code crashes because `nil` cannot be unwrapped.

To fix this you have to either have to

- explicitly check against `nil`
- or declare the variable as `var internetReachability: Reachability?` and deal with the optionals thorughout your code
- **or** make sure that the method `checkInternetConnection` is invoked before you try to access the `internetReachability`.

Luckily there is an easy version of the last option for you here by simply rearranging your code:

```
func checkInternetConnection () {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("reachabilityChanged"), name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)

    let remoteHostName: String = "www.apple.com"

    self.hostReachability = Reachability.init(hostName: remoteHostName)
    self.internetReachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    self.wifiReachability = Reachability.reachabilityForLocalWiFi()

    self.hostReachability.startNotifier()
    self.internetReachability.startNotifier()
    self.wifiReachability.startNotifier()

    self.updateInterfaceWithReachability(self.internetReachability)
    self.updateInterfaceWithReachability(self.wifiReachability)
    self.updateInterfaceWithReachability(self.hostReachability)
}
```

That way you make sure the three reachability types are all set before the `self.updateInterfaceWithReachability` tries to access them.